# La comparaison pour 3 personnes

Tags: comparatifs, coordination

Pour comparer 3 choses, est-ce qu'on peut dire « Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et Jean » ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les possibilités suivantes sont correctes et expriment la même idée;

> Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et Jean.
>   Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et plus que Jean (aussi).
>     Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et plus de livres que Jean.
>   Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et que Jean.

**Note** La dernière possibilité pourrait ne pas être très courante ; par exemple « que vous et que moi » est assez [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que+vous++et+que+moi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cque%20vous%20et%20que%20moi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cque%20vous%20et%20que%20moi%3B%2Cc0) de nos jours.

Pour dire que Pierre a plus de livres que n'en possèdent ensemble Pierre et Paul, on peut utiliser les formes suivantes.

> Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et Jean réunis.
>   Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et Jean n'en ont/possèdent ensemble.
>   Pierre a plus de livres que n'en ont/possèdent ensemble Paul et jean.

Comment: A noter que "Pierre a plus de livres que Paul et Jean" reste assez ambigu et pourrait facilement être compris comme " que Paul et Jean réunis". Cette ambiguïté peut je pense être levée avec "Pierre a plus de livres que Paul ou Jean".

Comment: @LaurentS. Cela pourrait être la meilleure façon de formuler la comparaison recherchée, et j'y avait bien pensé; mais j'avais conclu aussi que « ou » n'était pas beaucoup plus précis ; comme vous mettez ceci en question j'y pense encore et il me semble toujours que l'on peut encore se permettre un truchement sur le « ou » : « Pierre a plus de livres que Paul ou tout au moins Jean. » ; il faudrait encore autre chose, quelque chose comme « Pierre a plus de livres que Paul ou même Jean. » et dans ce cas on sous-entend que Jean a plus de livres que Paul en même temps.